# Plot frequency in 24 hours

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have data like this[image]

This is time of posting post of a Facebook page, i want to plot a line chart show which time in a day it usually post. Here is my code:

```
import scipy.interpolate as interp
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
raw['hour']=raw['time'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
ser = raw['hour'].value_counts()
ser_inter = interp.interp1d(np.arange(ser.size),ser)
ser_ = ser_inter(np.linspace(0,ser.size-1,raw['hour'].size))
plt.scatter(raw['hour'],ser_)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

Here is my plot:
[image]

I want to increase x axis interval so it will look less muddled. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73793171/reducing-the-number-of-labels-on-x-axis-of-plot) seems to have solution but only with xaxis's values display as year, I want it to display values only within 24hours.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.